# Translate html tag in magento 2

Tags: magento2, localisation

I have a html template with a string that's translated.
The translation contains a html a tag. but the tag is printed as text when rendered.

.html file content:

```
<p>{{trans "footer_link_privacy"}}</p>
```

en_US.csv content:

```
"footer_link_privacy", "<a href=""/en/privacy-policy"">Privacy Policy</a>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with

```
{{trans "footer_link_privacy"|raw}}
```

Comment: Lol, it never even occurred to me that this was twig. thanx man!

Comment: Is there equivalent raw filter in knockoutjs to use in html template?

Comment: try with this `<span data-bind="html: functionNameHere()"></span>`